# create auto increment number in view usiing information_schema php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, auto-increment

i want to generate the auto increment number in the view itself, so that  i can concatenate the string with that and insert into the db, currently I'm using the mysql db. 
eg: ext001
ext002
ext003
 every time in insert the new employee, new primary key will be incremented and i concatenated with string and insert to the db.

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: no, i have no idea how to do this